# why do these mysql queries run differently locally and on stage?

Tags: mysql

We have a query that when run locally returns quickly, but when that same query is run in our staging environment, it takes very long.

The local database is a copy of the stage database (as of it's last backup) so the two should be very similar.  When I run this explain command, I get very different results.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
    cs_uid
FROM mydb.article
WHERE cs_uid NOT IN (
    SELECT
        articleId
    FROM mydb.article_wordcount
);
```

LOCAL

```
id |select_type |table                |partitions |type  |possible_keys |key             |key_len |ref |rows   |filtered |Extra                    |
---|------------|---------------------|-----------|------|--------------|----------------|--------|----|-------|---------|-------------------------|
1  |PRIMARY     |article           |           |index |              |cs_importFileId |5       |    |179869 |100      |Using where; Using index |
2  |SUBQUERY    |article_wordcount |           |index |awc_articleId |awc_articleId   |4       |    |294816 |100      |Using index              |


STAGE

id |select_type |table                |type  |possible_keys |key           |key_len |ref |rows   |Extra       |
---|------------|---------------------|------|--------------|--------------|--------|----|-------|------------|
1  |PRIMARY     |article           |ALL   |              |              |        |    |269910 |Using where |
2  |SUBQUERY    |article_wordcount |index |awc_articleId |awc_articleId |4       |    |295417 |Using index |
```

The versions of mysql are similar, but not exactly the same:

Local: 5.7.24
Stage: 5.6.38

The differences I'm noticing in the explain command are:
* Seeing "partitions" and "filtered" columns locally, but not on stage
* "type" values for PRIMARY on local says "index", says "ALL" on stage

Does anyone have any ideas why the results are so different in the two environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the table definitions are the same, including same indexes with columns in the same order, then I'd lay the difference to differences/improvements in the optimizer in 5.7.

Looks like with 5.7, Oracle is choosing to use a covering index. In 5.6, it's accessing the actual table.

---

I'd avoid the `IN (subquery)` construct, and instead use an *anti-join* pattern. This will give a result mostly equivalent with the original; the big difference being the original won't return any rows if the subquery returns a NULL values.

```
  EXPLAIN
  SELECT a.cs_uid
    FROM mydb.article a
    LEFT
    JOIN mydb.article_wordcount c
      ON c.articleid = a.cs_uid
   WHERE c.articleid IS NULL
```

equivalent result with NOT EXISTS; EXPLAIN output will be very similar

```
  EXPLAIN
  SELECT a.cs_uid
    FROM mydb.article a
   WHERE NOT EXISTS 
         ( SELECT 1
             FROM mydb.article_wordcount c 
            WHERE c.articleid = a.cs_uid 
         )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Spencer.  I upgraded the stage DB to 5.7 and the explain is showing an index now.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is most likely because of the table sizes.  Also, the cardinality of the indexes may be different. Both of these affect how the database chooses the query plan.

Comment: 4 and 5 is the key length on local db. - but it's still 100.000 rows less, so hardly the exact same DB as OP is stating...

Comment: Oops, it's hard to read when the columns don't line up nicely.